# weird response from server with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, hosting

EDIT:
Apparently they add this to free hosting pages to prevent abuse. But I got rid of it by adding "exit;" on the end.
ENDofEDIT

I made a function called ajax, so I wouldn't have to write the code everywhere I need it and it works great.
But now as response I always get the data I expected as the response plus this:

```
<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->

<script type="text/javascript">

var sc_project=6961715; 

var sc_invisible=1; 

var sc_security="1ca8e3ee"; 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"

src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>

<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="tumblr stats"

href="http://statcounter.com/tumblr/" target="_blank"><img

class="statcounter"

src="http://c.statcounter.com/6961715/0/1ca8e3ee/1/"

alt="tumblr stats"></a></div></noscript>

<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
```

I check the data with if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){alert(xmlhttp.responseText);}

I'm sure the code is ok because it is the same code I used before. Here it is:

```
function ajax(adress, thenDo)
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            thenDo(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",adress,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

And I just checked it is on bottom on every page of mine on that server. (I'm using free hosting on hourb hosting)

Comment: If you've never seen that StatCounter stuff before, you may want to make sure your shared hosting provider isn't putting it in there.

Comment: well I newer noticed it before because I newer looked at the source code in the browser or used ajax on that hosting site, but I don't think it should be there. But I think I found where to send tickets to support.

Did anyone ever sow something like this?

Comment: add `exit;` to your ajax page to try and mitigate it. may not help but still

Comment: the exit command worked! thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly being added by your hosting provider, and its usage is one of the things that helps keep your free hosting free.

On the plus side, they would only be adding this for certain content-types, so you may want to check that your data is being returned as text/xml. If it is, then I would recommend contacting them directly, and asking if the configuration can be altered to exclude XML files.

Comment: It is a php page that sends the response, it is probably thinking it is php or html.

Comment: You should be able to find out using your browser's debug tools, and monitoring network requests. If it is coming back as text/html, then simply adding `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` may be sufficient.

Comment: At some free hostings adding exit(); at the end of the script supresses the counter.